How to Calculate Business Days Between Dates in Palantir
I would like to insert a column in Contour that displays business days between two date columns.
Any suggestions?
I tried using the date_diff function, but it doesn't calculate business days.
date_diff(start: date_time, end: date_time): number

you can use following script in "Expression"
here Date_to and Date_from is your start and end date columns
This exclude end date day
((CAST((5 * FLOOR((DATE_DIFF("Date_to", "Date_from") / 7))) AS INTEGER) 
+ CAST(ARRAY_GET_AT_INDEX(SPLIT('0012345501234544012343340123223401211234010012340', ''), 
((7 * (DAY_OF_WEEK("Date_from") - 1)) + DAY_OF_WEEK("Date_to"))) AS INTEGER)) + 0)

But if you want to include end date day as well then add +1
((CAST((5 * FLOOR((DATE_DIFF("Date_to", "Date_from") / 7))) AS INTEGER) 
+ CAST(ARRAY_GET_AT_INDEX(SPLIT('0012345501234544012343340123223401211234010012340', ''), 
((7 * (DAY_OF_WEEK("Date_from") - 1)) + DAY_OF_WEEK("Date_to"))) AS INTEGER)) + 1)

Example

